# Is there a way to reduce the blur caused by denoising while still reduce noise

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Im trying to reduce noise on my renders by using the denoise feature, but it makes the image very blurry specially the metallic parts, even when I reduce denoise strength to 0.2 it still has no effect, clamping indirect to 0.5 also doesnt help much. Also can't really afford to go beyond 500 samples to reduce the noise further since I got a long 2000 frame animation. Any other tricks or suggestions? Thanks
[image]